# Filling Jcombobox model

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to create combo box filled with letters from A to E but I faced two problems:

- Combo box won’t be filled unless I run it & click the number 1 then click it again to see it has been filled. (How it can be filled automatically?) -I have set 1, 2 from combobox proprties> model-

[image]
[image]

- After filling the combo box, I cannot choose other letter but A.

[image]

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String letters[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
        jComboBox1.addItem(letters.toString());
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(letters);
        jComboBox1.setModel(model);          
    }
```